# How to get the query string in PHP with the PHP built-in server?

Tags: php, server, query-string

I'm developing an MVC web app, and for its router to function I need to parse the query string, for which I need to load the URL into a variable in the first place. How do I achieve this with the PHP's built-in server?

I use PHP 7.3.9 at the moment, but as far as I can tell, the issue is persistent across all versions of a built-in server.

If I use Apache to run this app, everything is simple, all I need to do is

`$uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`
and I'm good to go, everything works just fine.

However, if I use PHP's built-in web server, I get an error saying:

`Undefined index: QUERY_STRING in /path_to_my_project/public/index.php on line 22`

I tried googling around and found [this pull request](https://github.com/miladrahimi/phprouter/pull/8) suggesting that such a variable truly doesn't exist in the PHP's built-in web server.

So my question is: how do I obtain the query string for my router if I run the built-in server, where `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` doesn't exist?

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is present for me with the built-in server on both 5.6.36 and 7.3.9.

Comment: So put code `die(var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));` in a `serve.php` and ran `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 serve.php` and I also get the undefined index in the commandline **but** I also get a dump of the query string on the browser window... which is odd.

Comment: Looks like it's only present when there is actually a query string on the request. Use `array_key_exists()` or null coalesce to avoid the notice. You're probably getting the error on Apache too, you just don't notice it because it doesn't normally get dumped to the console.

Comment: @AlexHowansky hmm, that's a very weird design indeed. It'd be much more intuitive to have it there anyways, just empty. Anyways, thanks for resolving it. I'll try to put an empty query to my URI if there is no such key in $_SERVER

Comment: Just use `$uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?? '';`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky could you please post it as an answer so that I could accept it? It's indeed the easiest way, especially in PHP 7 where the ?? operator is introduced so there's no longer a need to use ```array_key_exists()```

Comment: @AndyMac Done, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit: I fixed it, can you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is only present when there is actually a query string on the request. You can avoid this issue by using array_key_exists():

```
if (array_key_exists('QUERY_STRING', $_SERVER)) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
} else {
    $uri = '';
}
```

Or isset():

```
if (isset('QUERY_STRING', $_SERVER)) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
} else {
    $uri = '';
}
```

Or (simplest) via the null coalesce operator:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?? '';
```

Note that you're probably getting this error on Apache too, you just don't notice it because it doesn't normally get dumped to the console.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem... while operation is based on QUERY_STRING's value.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the same result by using `REQUEST_URI`, if this is available:

```
function getServerQueryString()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    {
        return $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
    {
        $xpl = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $baseName = $xpl[array_key_last($xpl)];

        if(strpos($baseName, '?') !== false)
        {
             return substr($baseName, strpos($baseName, '?')+1);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

echo $uri = getServerQueryString();
```

Some examples:

```
pageName.php?par1=val1&par2=val2...
// Output:
par1=val1&par2=val2...

pageName.php?
// Output:
     // empty

/some/path
// Output:
     // empty
```

Comment: There's apparently something wrong with this function. When I go to localhost:8100/setup/base, it returns just "ase" instead of "/setup/base" I expected it to. Probably something to do with what basename() does.

Just in case, I'm on Manjaro 18.1.0, 4.19 Kernel, PHP v. 7.3.9

Comment: what's the complete result of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: ```/setup/base```. Does this mean the whole basename() manipulation can be just cut out?

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit: I fixed it, can you try it?